# MySqlException on ExecuteReader by Selecting UserID(PK)

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I try to Delete a Row from the Database on the phpAdmin the Query is working
fine, but when I execute it with the

**Code:**

```
MySqlCommand getUserID = new MySqlCommand("SELECT UserID FROM User", connection);

MySqlDataReader reader = getUserID.ExecuteReader();
```

I get the

**Error:**

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length.

I Insert the to deleting user before without any trouble.

The Database has an `UserID` with properties `Unique`,`Int`(Length 9) and `Auto-Increment` and a `UserName` from type Char.

**My Question is:**

Why I can't receive the `userID` and how can I receive it ?

**Edit**

I can't receive any integer or date data only varchar.

Here is the Database creation query:
[Creation Query](http://database.s18447150.onlinehome-server.info/)

Comment: How big is your data? How many users are there in the Table?

Comment: Its a small table with 20 value´s

Comment: "non query" for a select?`SERIOUSLY? You are aware that "SELECT" is a query per definition? ExecuteNonQuery is meant for things not returning data (like UPDATE, DELETE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is the Database MySqlConnection can´t get Int or Date values if they are not unsigned, that also means the Exception:

> "Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length."

Answer (score 4):

The exception means that you are getting an unexpected result. The method ExecuteNonQuery tries to execute an query that returns no rows, and returns a integer displaying the amount of rows edited in the database. So it's trying to put the array of results into an integer field, which isn't possible.

So to answer your question, the cause of the error is the query. For select queries you should use the `ExecuteReader()` method.

Answer (score 4):

**Firstly** since you want to retrieve a single value (*`UserID`*) you could use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) here:

```
MySqlCommand getUserID = new MySqlCommand("SELECT UserID FROM `User`", connection);
connection.Open();
int userId = (int)getUserID.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
```

**Secondly** `User` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), so you need to use backticks around table name to make it explicit:

```
MySqlCommand getUserID = new MySqlCommand("SELECT UserID FROM `User`", connection);
```