# index was out of range when executing datareader

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm trying to connect to Mysql Database using UWP.

```
      objConn.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select city_ID,city_Name from cities", objConn);
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // <------ Here

      int i = 0;
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
         StudentsList.Items.Add("");
         StudentsList.Items.Add(dataReader.GetString(1).ToString());
         i++;
      }
      objConn.Close();
```

when I execute the code an error appears:

> index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name:startIndex

The error occurs when app reach this line:

```
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Check if columns and table names match the names given in the query

Comment: yes, they are the same ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, in my case the Problem was the Database. You should see that your integer Values are unsigned that means this error. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166670/mysqlexception-on-executenonquery-by-selecting-useridpk).

Answer (score 0):

when going out of range it means the value is not indexed example

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
console.writeline(myArray[6]);
```

you would get the going out of range exception for the reason that the index starts with Zero

Index: 0 1 2 3 4 5

Array: 1 2 3 4 5 6

So when you are using `(myArray[6]);` your actually pulling the 6th element in the index. If you notice it only goes to 5.

Comment: I think he know that. I was reading some unsavory problems concerning this one for him that may be a lot harder to debug. Hopefully I am wrong.